# How can I separate print output when using asp-perl

Tags: mod-perl

I'm trying to use asp-perl to pre-process some files that have embedded perl, asp style (probably doesn't matter, but it's not html).

for example:

```
want this <%="yes"%>
not this <%print "no" %>
```

I would like it to yield:

```
want this yes
not this
```

and have the 'no' end up in a different file or stream.

Is there some flag/configuration to enable this? I tried looking in CGI, Apache::ASP,... and nothing's jumping out at me.

EDIT. After burning a bunch of time in the debugger, I've found that overriding these two subs gives me the result I want. a bit of a hack. I guess I only needed the first sub. The second is to avoid writing to a file.

```
sub Apache::ASP::InitPackageGlobals {
  my $self = shift;

  # unless ($self->{response_tied}) {
  #   # set printing to Response object
  #   $self->{response_tied} = 1;
  #   tie *RESPONSE, 'Apache::ASP::Response', $self->{Response};
  #   select(RESPONSE);
  # }

  # ---- init package objects ----
  # unoptimized this because we should only call this function once
  # and maybe twice if there is a defined Script_OnStart
  for my $object (@Apache::ASP::Objects) {
    for my $import_package (@{$self->{init_packages}}) {
      my $init_var = $import_package.'::'.$object;
      $$init_var = $self->{$object};
    }
  }

  undef;
}

my $parse_results = "";
sub Apache::ASP::CGI::print {
  shift;
  $parse_results .= join("", map { ref($_) =~ /SCALAR/ ? $$_ : $_; } @_); 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the asp-classic tag is helping you get any answers.

Comment: @John - any suggestions for a better tag?

Comment: Well I know classic ASP but I have never heard of asp-perl. Maybe a perl tag might be better???